# Sublime Text toggleNeoVintageous plugin

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed the toggle neo vintageous plugin for sublime text and set the key to ctrl+Alt+t, to toggle neovintageous. When I toggle it on it works, but when I toggle it of I get this error message:

> Error loading syntax file
>   "Packages/NeoVintageous/res/Command-linemode.sublime-syntax":Unable to
>   read Packages/NeoVintageous/res/Command-linemode.sublime-syntax

Does any one know what it means, although it still toggles off after the error message, but I don't know why it keeps popping up whenever i try to do that

Comment: This shouldn't happen in the latest versions of NeoVintageous because the command line mode syntax has been removed. @OdatNurd is right in that the issue happens when the ex mode panel is open when toggling NeoVintageous off. Again, this won't happen in newer versions because the syntax is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

> Error loading syntax file "Packages/NeoVintageous/res/Command-linemode.sublime-syntax":Unable to read Packages/NeoVintageous/res/Command-linemode.sublime-syntax

Generically speaking, this error message is telling you that there is something somewhere in Sublime (an open file or other widget) that thinks that it should be using a specific syntax definition, but that syntax definition can't be found. The syntax file named is the one that's causing the error.

If we examine the filename it mentions (`Packages/NeoVintageous/res/Command-linemode.sublime-syntax`) we can determine that the syntax file is in the NeoVintageous package itself.

In Sublime, any package that's installed is always "turned on" and active unless it's name appears in the `ignored_packages` setting, which tells Sublime that even though the package exists, it should pretend that it doesn't.

It's not explicitly stated anywhere in the README for this package, but all it's doing is modifying that setting on your behalf to either add or remove the NeoVintageous plugin to the setting.

When you add a package to the list of ignored packages when it's already loaded, Sublime responds by unloading the package from memory and acting like it does not exist.

So, taken all together, the problem that you're having here is that you have NeoVintageous turned on, something in Sublime is using a syntax definition from that package, and then when you toggle the package off, the syntax definition is unloaded and Sublime complains because the syntax it wants to use is no longer available.

I don't use either of those packages personally, but based on the name of the syntax being `Command-linemode.sublime-syntax` my guess would be that the syntax is being used in the `ex` command input that you can use to give `ex` commands to the package (probably to allow for auto complete or something like that).

If that's the case, you can probably stop the error from being displayed by closing the command window before you toggle the state of the package. I would imagine that the error popup would go away and not recur once the command input was closed, so the error is annoying but more or less harmless.

It may be worth raising an issue with the package author to let them know what's happening, if for no other reason than they can document that this will happen or modify this package to not be able to toggle the state of the package off while the syntax is currently in use.